# Android Patterns.WEB_URL broken?

Tags: android, regex

So, can someone explain what happened to the trailing slash here in my test? Or is it a bug with the *WEB_URL* pattern?

```
@Test
public void testWebUrl() {
    String url = "http://www.google.com/foo/";
    String test = "A string that fails is this: " + url + " <-- see that?";

    Matcher m = Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(test);
    while (m.find()) {
        assertTrue(Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(url).matches());  // PASSES
        assertEquals(m.group(), url);  // FAILS
        // Here, m.group() == "http://www.google.com/foo", without the trailing "/"
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! I am having the same issue. Did you find any solution that does not involve creating you own WEB_URL custom pattern?

Comment: It also failing for link that is written like this `https://google.com/foo/`